# pypyodbc.DatabaseError: (u'07002', u'[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access \u9a71\u52a8\u7a0b\u5e8f] Too few parameters. Expected 1.'

Tags: python, ms-access

I want to updata table 户结构查询结果 in access by python2

when I execute:

```
    cur.execute(u"UPDATE 户结构 SET 抽样数=(SELECT 抽样数 FROM 户结构查询结果 WHERE 户结构查询结果.行政区=户结构.行政区 AND 户结构查询结果.户结构=户结构.户规模)" ).commit()
```

I get the following error:

```
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: (u'07002', u'[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access \u9a71\u52a8\u7a0b\u5e8f] Too few parameters. Expected 1.')
```

my tables are following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcogA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW5m3.png)

all type of fields is text（255）

Answer (score 1):

Your update syntax is wrong, since you can't use a subquery in an update.

Use the following:

```sql
UPDATE 户结构
INNER JOIN 户结构查询结果 ON 户结构查询结果.行政区=户结构.行政区 AND 户结构查询结果.户结构=户结构.户规模
SET 抽样数 = 抽样数
```

Note that I'm not that good at reading these characters, so I can't verify the field names and table names are valid.